# Spring JPA Specification IN with Predicate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to accomplish the following sql query with JPA Specification's class.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Path p
WHERE p.path_id IN (
  SELECT s2.path_id
  FROM segment s2
  INNER JOIN segment_end s3 ON s2.segment_id = s3.segment_id
  WHERE s3.site_name = 'ABC' and s3.passive_flag=false)
AND p.path_id IN (
  SELECT s2.path_id
  FROM segment s2
  INNER JOIN segment_end s3 ON s2.segment_id = s3.segment_id
  WHERE s3.site_name = 'ART CENTER' and s3.passive_flag=false
);
```

Trying to get something to the affect of this:

```
   List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
   Expression<String> sfExpression = null;
   List<Predicate> siteNamePredicates = new ArrayList<>();
   Expression<String> site1Expression = pathRoot.join("segments", JoinType.LEFT)
     .join("segmentEnds", JoinType.LEFT)
     .get(pathSearch.getPathSearchField().get().toString());

   siteNamePredicates.add(cb.equal(site1Expression.in(site1Expression), "ABC"));

   Expression<String> site2Expression = pathRoot.join("segments", JoinType.LEFT)
     .join("segmentEnds", JoinType.LEFT)
     .get(pathSearch.getPathSearchField().get().toString());

   siteNamePredicates.add(cb.equal(site2Expression.in(site2Expression), "ART CENTER"));

   predicates.add(cb.and(siteNamePredicates.toArray(new Predicate[siteNamePredicates.size() -1])));

   return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size() - 1]));
```

The reason for using specifications is that we are allowing our application to AND other search criteria so using `CriteriaBuilder` allows me to use `predicates`.

Any help would be appreciated.